# Return all possible pairs combinations of values for a single column in SQL

Tags: combinations

I would like to get all ***DISTINCT*** pairs combination to follow table :

Table Name: `Dancer`

```
 id  name  
 1  Yaniv  
 2  Dan   
 3  Eli   
 4  Guy   
 5  Sara  
 6  Naama  
 7  Suzi   
 8  Vered
```

*The results should be like this :

```
pairs  
Yaniv Dan  
Yaniv Eli  
Yaniv Guy  
Yaniv Sara  
Yaniv Naama  
Yaniv Suzi  
Yaniv Vered  
Dan Eli  
Dan Guy  
Dan Sara  
Dan Naama  
Dan Suzi  
Dan Vered  
Guy Sara  
Guy Naama  
Guy Suzi  
Guy Vered  
Sara Naama  
Sara Suzi  
Sara Vered  
Naama Suzi  
Naama Vered  
Suzi Vered
```

I tried `CROSS JOIN + WHERE` clause to eliminate the identical names as `Yaniv Yaniv,Dan Dan`...etc
BUT I get also multiple pairs combinations as

```
Yaniv Dan    
Dan Yaniv
```

How can I filter these multiple pairs..??
this is my SQL code :

```
Select D2.name + ' ' + D1.name  
From Dancer D1  
Cross join   
Dancer D2  
Where D1.name<>D2.name
```

Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Please don't write anything in uppercase, it's considered as screaming on the internet. Also, this question is way too broad and not understandable.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this question is very broad: It's unclear what your tables look like exactly (it's always a good idea to give a bit of actual sample data, along with how the table schema looks), and it's unclear what you've tried or where you're stuck, output you're getting (actual vs what you're expecting), etc. And then there's the topic of SQL itself: SQL queries vary, depending on what database engine you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get all the column of names with all other names in the same column this would be considered a Cartesian join.

Would be something like the following:

```
   Select a.Name +' ' + b.Name as ResultName
   from Table as a, Table as b
```

This works if your Name column contains like you described : John, Yaniv, Dan .. would results in John Yaniv, John Name, Yaniv John, Yaniv Dan.  If however your names have multiple parts like Sarah T you will only get the single name with other names. Example:  Sarah T John, Sarah T Yaniv, etc.  It will not break down Sarah and T into separate results.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it BUT i get multiple combination as : John Yaniv; Yaniv John.

Comment: In a cross join / Cartesian select you will get exactly every possible combination of terms.  If you only want distinct terms regardless of orientation I think while I believe it could be possible maybe with SQL via some form of recursion, in my opinion be better served as a coding exercise than a SQL query.

Comment: @Lynyrd - Probably best not to answer questions that are off-topic. This particular question is very broad, and you're giving an answer based on a schema you created (the OP hasn't provided any) - it's not even clear if the names are space-separated in a single field, multiple fields for parts of the name, etc. Giving feedback for improving comments? A great idea, and best to put those in a comment under the question, to help the OP improve their question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon -  I will keep this in mind, thanks.. The question was very broad and in the initial form of the question did describe a basic structure of data in single column of data in a table though in the latest version of the question as it now  appears that was been completely removed/replaced.